# Jquery Autocomplete Doesn't Work for The First Key

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I use jQuery UI autocomplete plugin in my Struts 1 application. It works, but when I press the key for the first time it does not, but later it works.

```
var res=null;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    click();
});

function click()
{
    $( "#me" ).keyup(function(e)
    {
        var value=$("#me").val();
        if(e.keyCode>64 && e.keyCode<91)
        {
            callserver(value);
        }
    });
}
//var my_delay=20000;

function callserver(value)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<%=cPath%>/lims/index",
        data: {action:"retrive autocomplete",name:value },
        cache:false,
        })
        .done(function( namelist ){
            res=namelist.split(",");
            $( "#me" ).autocomplete({
                source: res
                });
            res=null;
            //click();
            });
}
```

I retrieve the value from Oracle DB.

Comment: Can you explain what your trying to do??

Comment: Because you're not initializing the plugin until you get into the `keypress` handler. You should initialize the plugin in the `ready` function.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write your own `keypress` handler to use autocomplete, it's done by the widget for you. Just initialize the widget in the `$(document).ready()` handler, and tell it to get the values using AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#me").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<%=cPath%>/lims/index",
                data: {action:"retrive autocomplete", name: request.term },
                cache:false,
            })
            .done(function( namelist ){
                res=namelist.split(",");
                response(res);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi barmaer,I tried with ur code but again error on console.error is this source not a fuction

Comment: I was missing a brace, try it now

Comment: Ya I put that bracess but it throww error in crome console is Object is nat a function

Comment: in jquery ui.cs which was i download from jquery ui domain.the error is this.source not a function

Comment: Typo, `src` should be `source`.

Comment: how to add two auto complete in one page.i mean two ready function i write or ???@Barmer

Comment: Just call `.autocomplete` twice: `$("#input1").autocomplete(<options>); $("#input2").autocomplete(<options>);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#me").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%=cPath%>/path",
            data: {action:"retrive autocomplete", name: request.term },
            cache:false,
        })
        .done(function( namelist ){
            res=namelist.split(",");
            response(res);
        });
    }
});
```